# Displaying 'list out of range' when using numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am using `numpy` to generate a 2D array, but getting an error when attempting to access with a specific index.

```
MaxIt=100
PopSize = 30
w=1
c1=2
c2=2

#Intialisation
empty_particle = {'position': None,
                  'velocity': None,
                  'cost': None,
                  'best_position': None,
                  'best_cost': None}
gbest = {'position': None, 'cost': np.inf}

# Create Initial Population
pop = [];
for i in range(0, PopSize):
    pop.append(empty_particle.copy())

    pop[i]['position'] = np.random.uniform(VarMin, VarMax, nVar)
    pop[i]['velocity'] = np.zeros(nVar)
    pop[i]['cost'] = CostFunction(pop[i]['position'])
    pop[i]['best_position'] = pop[i]['position'].copy()
    pop[i]['best_cost'] = pop[i]['cost']
    if pop[i]['best_cost'] < gbest['cost']:
            gbest['position'] = pop[i]['best_position'].copy()
            gbest['cost'] = pop[i]['best_cost']
    pop[2]['position']
```

Last line is showing the error.  I just want to print the second element in the list `pop`, i.e. `pop[2]`

Comment: Please add MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and error.

Comment: `pop` starts empty.  You add an element, and set values with `pop[0]`.  But then try to do something with `pop[2]`, when the number of elements is only 1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic principle of python is that tabs work like brackets in other languages. You are trying to print elements of your array while still building up the array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @efkah's answer:

Your question states you want to access the **second** item in the `pop` list.  However, when you reference `pop[2]`, **this is the third item**, as iterables work from a zero base.

This could be the trigger of your 'index out of range' error.